Error 401 calling asp.net webapi on aws with cognito
error in postman is
Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer 'https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxx' is invalid"
which doesn't make sense since the token is obtained using the same userpool id
[HttpGet]
[Route("listp")]
[Authorize]
public string Getp()    {
    return "this is a secure call ";
}

the program.cs relevant code is - from here
builder.Services.AddCognitoIdentity();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    var cfg = builder.Configuration["Cognito:Authority"];
    /*
    options.MetadataAddress = $"{cfg}.well-known/openid-configuration";
    //options.Authority = builder.Configuration["Cognito:Authority"];
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
}

also tried the code from this sample here but same error
environment is asp.net 8 on aws, client is react-native app
